# How to receive BOOT_COMPLETED on Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm developing an app for Android TV. I have a sticky service & a broadcast receiver that should restart this service after system reboot.

The code works perfect for any phone, but, in the case of the TV, any of the actions that I defined in the receiver's intent isn't received, when turning on the TV from standby(using the remote). It works when I unplug the TV and plug it again.

Has anyone tried something similiar? Any advice might help. Thanks

I've tried  `BOOT_COMPLETED`, `QUICKBOOT_POWERON`, `REBOOT`, `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED`.

Here is the receiver I've configured.

```
<receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:directBootAware="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" 
/>
            <action 
android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT" />
            <action 
android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action 
android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Expected to catch the action of turning on the device in the broadcast.

Comment: Did you fin a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have added following permission.

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
```